# Why is triangle used instead of Quad?

Tags: modeling, topology, optimization

Why is triangle used instead of Quad?
Why is triangle used instead of quad in the first screenshot as in the 2nd screenshot?
I thought diamond shaped quads could be used?

[image]

[image]

I'm sorry, because I was sick, I couldn't look at the computer. In one of the videos I watched, while optimizing the model, highpoly used it this way in the other, I wondered why he used it, I couldn't understand why they did it. Can you suggest a source that can give me information about this subject?

Comment: You can use triangles as long as it doesn't create any problem

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, the use of quad and tris is a bit of the artist's choice.

Comment: If tris don't bother you when you work on your topology, and if it doesn't create any artefact when rendered, it's ok to use them, same for ngons. Using only quads is often cited as a rule because it prevents this kind of problems, but as soon as you understand why and when it creates problem you can use them

Comment: You can use tris in hardsurface modeling, only optionally. Hardsurface modeling requires less details in the mesh than deformable objects requiring more quads than the former. Quads have advantages. For example, it is easy to select rings of edges or faces, or box-select areas.

Answer (score 6):

If tris don't bother you when you work on your topology, and if it doesn't create any artefact when rendered, it's ok to use them, same for ngons. Using only quads is often cited as a rule because it prevents this kind of problems, but as soon as you understand why and when it creates problem you can use them.

In your case tris or quads will give the exact same result. But using quads won't represent any advantage, it will even make the selection of the half-circle edge more tedious, if you want to create a bevel for example:

[image]

If your shape is meant to stay like this, use tris. If you plan to create extrusion for example, a better topology would be this one:

[image]

[image]